# Why the breakout environment is the same with different seed?

Tags: openai-gym

```
import gymnasium as gym 
import numpy as np
for s in [0,1,2,3,4]:  
    env=gym.make("BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4")
    observation, info = env.reset(seed=s)
    print(s, np.sum(observation))
```

I tried the bellowing code and found out the initial state of breakout environment is the same with different seed. I wonder why? And how to get a different initial state?

Comment: outputs:0 4113104;
1 4113104;
2 4113104;
3 4113104;
4 4113104;

Answer (score 0):

##### First of all, it is not safe ...

*First of all, it is not safe to check the difference of states by comparing the sum of pixel values, especially for Breakout environment.*

This is because the movement of the ball and paddle cannot be catched by the sum of the pixel. The paddle is always red with fixed width and height, so as the ball. You can figure out easily from the result of the code below:

```
import gymnasium as gym 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

env = gym.make("BreakoutNoFrameskip-v4")

num_repeat = 10

plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,5)

for seed in range(10):
    s0, _ = env.reset(seed=seed)
    for i in range(num_repeat):
        s1, *_ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    print(seed, np.sum(s0), np.sum(s1))
    ax[seed//5, seed%5].imshow(s1, interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

Resulted 10 images might be slightly different, but the sum of the pixel values be all equal.

---

##### **Back to your question,**

*It seems that the Breakout environment itself has no stochastic factor, i.e., it is deterministic environment.* You can heuristically check this:

```
num_repeat = 50
predetermined_actions = np.random.choice(env.action_space.n, num_repeat)

plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,5)

for seed in range(10):
    s0, _ = env.reset(seed=seed)
    for i in range(num_repeat):
        s1, *_ = env.step(predetermined_actions[i])
    print(seed, np.sum(s0), np.sum(s1))
    ax[seed//5, seed%5].imshow(s1, interpolation='nearest')

plt.show()
```

Whatever `seed` you set, if the action sequence is exactly the same, the output states are always identical.

*Then, how to use `seed` correctly in Breakout environment, which is already deterministic?*

```
    s0, _ = env.reset()
    env.action_space.seed(seed)
```

As metioned on [document](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env), you can set a seed to an action space.